# Auto correlation of a row vector

Tags: signal-processing, matlab-compiler, telecommunication, software-defined-radio

I want to take auto correlation of a row vector of length 1x2080, as i want to take first 52 numbers(from 0 to 52) and then correlate with this row then i want to take from next 52 from (1 to 53) and then so on for example next i will take next 52 (2 to 54) and the correlate this with row so at the end of the day i can check where the auto correlation is high.I am trying to implement a for loop for that for example for i = 1:52:2080
                    autocorr(i+51,a)
end
where a contains the row vector of containing numbers for autocorrelation